# Error: application.yml not found, see config/application.yml.example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running my ruby on rails application and it was working fine. Because of some application requirement I had to make the changes in my application.yml file in config folder. So I did those changes in application.yml.example file and then replaced the existed application.yml file with application.yml.example.

So the new application.yml have all the modification which I wanted . But after this when I am running my application Phusion passenger is giving me error:

```
application.yml not found, see config/application.yml.example
```

But the application.yml is present in my application , i have just modified its content.

This is my log file:

```
FakeEpicServer#start done.
Starting fake epic server
WEBrick 1.3.1
ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
FakeEpicServlet is mounted on /.
#<WEBrick::HTTPServlet::ProcHandler:0x007f87bfd9fa50 @proc=# <Proc:0x007f87bfd9fb18 (lambda)>> is mounted on /wsdl.
FakeEpicServer#start: pid=19222 port=56043
Creating epic interface
close TCPSocket(0.0.0.0, 56043)
close TCPSocket(::, 56043)
going to shutdown ...
FakeEpicServer#start done.
```

Full Error on Phusion:

```
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/config/initializers/audit_trail.rb:27:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/config/initializers/audit_trail.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
  /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
 /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
 /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
 /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
 /opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/config/environment.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:23:in `require'
config.ru:23:in `block in <main>'
/opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
/home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
 /home/mskhan2/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

file permission:

```
mskhan2@askeott:/opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/config$ stat application.yml
File: ‘application.yml’
Size: 7913          Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 1309105     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1010/ mskhan2)   Gid: ( 1012/ mskhan2)
Access: 2016-08-19 14:43:23.663483744 -0400
Modify: 2016-08-19 14:43:00.823483523 -0400
Change: 2016-08-19 14:43:00.823483523 -0400
Birth: -
=============================================================================
mskhan2@askeott:/opt/cnmc-sparc-request-master-june/config$ stat database.yml
File: ‘database.yml’
Size: 2252          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 1352614     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1010/ mskhan2)   Gid: ( 1012/ mskhan2)
Access: 2016-08-19 11:02:36.987355521 -0400
Modify: 2016-06-30 12:18:54.033583629 -0400
Change: 2016-06-30 12:18:54.045583629 -0400
Birth: -
```

Comment: Are you using Atom as the your text editor?

Comment: No, I have simply used Geany editor on my linux machine and then uploaded the file on my server where my application is running.

Comment: is the file tracked in .gitignore or are you using any version control system? Sound like when uploading the files the server ignores it simply because it's not being track

Comment: I am not using Github anywhere. I have full application on my local machine and copy of application on my server. if i need to make changes I make changes in my local machine and replace the file on Server.

Comment: So you've no way to compare what was in your application.yml before you overwrote it with your altered version of application.yml.example?

Comment: No I can, i have a backupcopy of that. I have just added one line to modify this-- user_portal_link: 'http://localhost/portal' and after that it's not working.

Comment: Check the permissions and ownership. I would guess that you created the file as root (you didn't edit the existing file, so it means the new file inherited permission and ownership from your user) and phusion doesn't have permission to read it.

Comment: do I need to check the permission of file ? can u help me how I can check the permission and ownership.

Comment: I checked the permission and the permissions and ownership are same as of other .yml files which are already there (which i didn't change).

check my question I have updated, you can see the permission of two files.

Comment: go to config/ folder and do `ls -als` to see the permissions of the files in that directory

Comment: Ok so the permission is root, how I can change it to my username which is 'mskhan2'

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root    root     7913 Aug 19 14:58 application.yml